# asp.net mvc 2 project does not render data annotation attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

what can a problem that data annotation attributes are not rendered?

web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

C#

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    [Required]
    public string ControlNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Insured { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Core.SearchCriteria>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Core" %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.ControlNo) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ControlNo) %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ControlNo) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Insured) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Insured) %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Insured) %>
            </div>
```

Comment: Isn't that part of the "unobtrusive javascript" feature from mvc 3?

Comment: the problem is that html <input /> doesn't have data annotation attributes

Comment: "Isn't that part of the "unobtrusive javascript" feature from mvc 3?"  unobtrusive javascript analyses data annotation attributes but MVC engine has to render them.  My problem that MVC does not render.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx is a  proof that it exists in MVC 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with validation was that MVC 2 does not render data annotation attributes !!!

instead MVC 2 creates JS object that defines all validation rules and then MicrosoftMvcValidation.js works with it.

Comment: Which points back to my comment...they are rendered as part of a feature of mvc3, not mvc2.

Comment: µBio yes you asked the right question but I did not find it helpful on the beginning.